# YII ajax validation: The error message doesnt appear afer ajax validation

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, yii

I have 2 fields in the form (num1 and num2), sum of which forms variable, entered to the databases (sum), which is required. There are some other required fields .

```
array('summ ', 'required'),
```

In other words in order to get this variable I need two of these fields (num1 and num2). Without ajaxom validation I solve this problem by:

```
if($_POST['num1'] && $_POST['num2']) {
    $model->sum = $_POST['num1'] + $_POST['num2'];
} else {
    $model->sum='';
}
```

Here is code of form’s part:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'bithday', array('class' => 'label_register')); ?>
<input name="num1" type="text" value="">
<input name="num2" type="text" value="">
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'bithday'); ?>
```

After forwarding ajax request, the response containing error messages. But the error doesn’t appear. Though errors of other required fields appear correctly. 
Response comes in form of json, with key and it’s value. (Data about this error is contained here)
How to solve this problem? .

Answer (score 0):

Use the Yii textfield like so:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'num1', array('class' => 'label_register'));
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'num1'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'num1'); ?>

<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'num2', array('class' => 'label_register'));
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'num2'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'num2'); ?>
```

And add the properties $num1 and $num2 to your model.